# How to change the layout of displaying in FoxPro98?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I would like to know if there is a way of changing the layout of foxpro98 when I list a table.

Right now when I list something it looks like this:[bad looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuH0x.png)

I tried playing with settings but it didn't work.

Comment: Which version of Visual Foxpro? There is no Foxpro98. How do you want it to display, and have you looked at the help for the `List` command?

Comment: My bad. The version that I'm using is 6, VFP6. I would like to be displayed more organised and with no such spaces between columns.

Comment: The help file for VFP 9 doesn't show any options for changing the spacing between columns, so I doubt its possible in 6. I would probably look at changing the font.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it comes down to whether you want the data shown **On-Screen** or do you want to be able to hand it to another recipient (**Off-system**).

For On-Screen viewing - use **BROWSE** as we have suggested above. The viewer can see all of the record data and they can readily SCROLL through the Browse Window to view anything that is not immediately on-screen.

For Off-System viewing - use VFP's **Report Form** to generate a Report. In that Form you can specify the Font, the Font Size, Position, everything and even have it come out in Landscape vs Portrait mode.

You might want to look at the Basic Reporting tutorial videos at:  [Free VFP Tutorial Videos](http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx)

BTW: don't EVER use a **Wizard** (not the Screen Form Wizard or the Report Form Wizard) to create something.  Yes it can give you quick results, but you will not **LEARN** anything about how or why it is done, You have an opportunity to **LEARN** if you do it 'by hand'.

**LIST** is not really intended for an end-result or anything other than a quick peek at things.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You can play with _screen font. However, it is much easier to use a BROWSE command instead.

If you really want to List to screen like that, then check the 'fields' clause.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a Wrap-Around of the Header (field names) and of each record.

Do you **NEED** to use **LIST**?
Or can you use **BROWSE**?
Even with BROWSE you will most likely have to Scroll to the Right to see the right-most fields and their values, but each record will all be contained within a single non-wrapped row.

Another very secondary option would be to output the table data to a CSV file and then open it in a VFP - **MODIFY FILE** window for viewing.

```
SELECT ThisDBF
COPY TO c:\temp\temp.CSV CSV
MODIFY FILE c:\temp\temp.csv
```

NOTE: The CSV file 'records' themselves will not be wrapped-around, but if the viewing 'window' is not a wide as the record length, what you see will appear as wrapped-around but it really is not.

Comment: You can use Modify Command instead of Modify File to prevent wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using report that is also printable.
Usually our goal is to prepare a software for our client or for some other staff of company so they need also printable version. There is very good report wizard in vfp9 (don't remember if it exist in vfp6 but you can easily make a report without wizard from table).

Comment: Do you ever use a report for quickly checking the contents of a table?

Comment: @CetinBasoz it is not mentioned in question that it is only for checking the contents of table. but if it is so, then your answer should be accepted and you are right there is not a good command as compare to BROWSE in VFP.